# Samsung Galaxy SII camera blank

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, camera

The camera in a Samsung Galaxy SII GT-I9100 shows a black screen. Photos cannot be taken either. However, pressing the shutter does seem to activate the flash sometimes. Even the front cam fails!

I've tried flashing a few custom ROMs (4.3 based Carbon ROM) over recovery. The ROM works, but the camera gives the same result.
I even tried to flash an official JellyBean stock ROM for S2 via Odin. Camera still fails.

Logcat (filter level: 'error') shows:-

```
E/SecCameraHardware( 1839): nativeGetPreview: warning, ESD reset the camera device (6)
E/SecCameraHardware( 1839): FimcV4l2 poll: error 0
E/SecCameraHardware( 1839): nativeGetPreview: warning, ESD reset the camera device (5)
E/SecCameraHardware( 1839): FimcV4l2 poll: error 0
E/SecCameraHardware( 1839): nativeGetPreview: warning, ESD reset the camera device (4)
E/SecCameraHardware( 1839): FimcV4l2 poll: error 0
E/SecCameraHardware( 1839): nativeGetPreview: warning, ESD reset the camera device (3)
```

The worst I could fear is the camera sensor being busted, but is there any other software level stuff I could possibly try out?

Comment: have u solved it in any way?
I have the1 same problem with my samsung.
Thank you very much

Comment: @ALEX I don't have the device with me anymore; it seems like the camera IC or some part responsible for it was damaged. More of a hardware issue.